# Meteor Mongo.Cursor returns duplicate rows in Tracker.autorun

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular-meteor

I am converting Mongo.Cursor to array using fetch() in Tracker.autorun and assigning it to the `songsArray`. But each time the underlying database is changed(reactively), I see duplicate values in `songsArray`

```
private songsArray:Array<any>;
songsCursor:Mongo.Cursor<any>;

//...Some code here
ngOnInit():any {
//... Some code here

    this.songsCursor = Songs.find();
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        this.songsArray = [];
        this.songsArray = this.songsCursor.fetch();
    });
}
```

Why is it happening and if I assume I am doing it wrong, then what is the correct way to convert cursors to array in `Tracker.autorun`?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you need to do something like this:

```
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);

// Subscribe to collections here:
    this.subscribe('songs');

    this.helpers({
      songs: () => Songs.find()
    });
```

and you'll find *songs* is an array like you want

Comment: I am on angular 2 so $scope etc... won't work. Also I am using angular-templates instead of blade.

Comment: My apologies, this is code that works with Angular 1.5, and should be applicable in concept to Angular 2, except for the $scope reference. The point is that if you subscribe to a collection you shouldn't need to worry about Tracker. You can use getReactively on a variable in your helper to ensure that the collection is fetched reactively.